# Discord.py command that deletes messages doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror, coroutine

I'm trying to make a command that deletes a number of messages I want, but it doesn't work.

I got this error:

> 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'delete'.

```py
if message.content.startswith("!נקה"):
    delete_count = 0
    try:
        value = message.content.split("!נקה ",1)[1] #gets the value of the messages I want to delete
        value = int(value)
        flag = 1
    except:
        flag = 0
        msg = await message.channel.send("שכחת לכתוב כמה הודעות למחוק.")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
    if flag == 1:
        for i in range(value-1):
            if True:
                with open("messagesList.txt", "r") as json_file:
                    messagesList = json.load(json_file) #loads a list of the id of messages
                message_id = messagesList[0]
                msg = message.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
                await msg.delete()
                delete_count += 1
                with open("messagesList.txt", "w") as json_file:
                    json.dump(messagesList, json_file)
            else:
                print("", end = "")
        if delete_count != 0:
            message = await message.channel.send(f"{delete_count}הודעות נמחקו בהצלחה.") #prints the messages successfully delete
        await asyncio.sleep(3) #wait 3 seconds
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create something like a [`purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) command? If you want to simply delete some amount of messages from the channel (without other operations), then try this:

```py
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount = 5): # you can set the default amount of messages that will be deleted (if you didn't specify the amount while running the command)
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1) # adding one to remove "clear" command too
    await ctx.send(f"Deleted {len(deleted)} messages") # sends how many messages were deleted
```

[Commands in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands)

Answer (score 0):

The error should be here:

```py
  except:
    flag = 0
    msg = await message.channel.send("שכחת לכתוב כמה הודעות למחוק.")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.delete() #The problematic line.
```

`msg` is a coroutine, not a [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message) object. It doesn't have a delete attribute.

You can simply use the [`delete_after=time`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) parameter:

```py
  except:
    flag = 0
    msg = await message.channel.send("שכחת לכתוב כמה הודעות למחוק.", delete_after=5)
```

Another way is to make the bot delete the message, as you've tried:

```py
  except:
    flag = 0
    msg = await message.channel.send("שכחת לכתוב כמה הודעות למחוק.")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.delete_message(msg)
```

It's explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161009/16136190).

Comment: it didnt solve my error. the error is in the if condition, in the line "await msg.delete()", after the line "msg = message.channel.fetch_message(message_id)".

Comment: @ThemagicIL oh. Does changing that line to `await bot.delete_message(msg)` work?